# android mjpeg streaming error

Tags: android, video-streaming, mjpeg

I need to view mjpeg stream on android device.  I found mjpegview and  [this library](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplemjpegview). But when I configured ip address and port on its async doRead method gets stream I can see its content when debugging. But not shows in the mjpegview. I download that apk of that library from [playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tk.android.simplemjpeg) it also didnt do streaming.

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dngames.mjpegviewer) plays my stream on same device.

Any idea  for that?  Or  suggest something ?